# Property Type Does Not Exist - MongoDB WithId<Document>

Tags: typescript, mongodb, types, collections

### Using:

- ts-node: 10.7.0
- MongoDB: 4.4.1
- GraphQL: 16.3

I am trying to get a response back from a mongo db request.

The request is successfully coming back, but typescript is throwing errors related to properties not existing on the type. I have declared the interface.

### The error I am getting is (on 3rd console log in code below):

```
Property 'schema' does not exist on type 'WithId<Document>[]'
```

### Code:

```
    interface permissionSchemaCollectionResponse extends WithId<Document> {
      _id: ObjectId; 
      collection: string;
      schema: any;
    }
  
    const permissionSchemaCollectionResponse = (await 
    permissionSchemaCollection.find(filter).toArray());
    
    console.log('permissionSchemaCollectionResponse');
    console.log(permissionSchemaCollectionResponse);

    console.log(permissionSchemaCollectionResponse.schema.record);
```

### Response from Mongo:

```
permissionSchemaCollectionResponse
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("62093b950759ba6867f477e2"),
    collection: 'apps',
    schema: { record: [Object], properties: [Object] }
  }
]
```

## Attempt at adding a "model":

permissions.ts

```
import type { WithId, Document, ObjectId } from 'mongodb'

export default class PermissionSchema {
    constructor(public id: ObjectId, public collection: string, public schema: any) {}
}
```

### Response using "as" imported model:

```
const  permissionSchemaCollectionResponse = (await permissionSchemaCollection.find(filter).toArray()) as PermissionSchema[];
```

### Error when using imported model

```
Conversion of type 'WithId<Document>[]' to type 'PermissionSchema[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
```

Comment: can you show the code where you declare the schema and model?

Comment: @TobiasS. I have to declare a model? I cannot just write the interface extending WithId<Document>. Added a snippet of an earlier attempt where I'm presented with a type conversion error.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up being both a typing and trying to access a array as an attribute errors.

Resolved with:

#### model:

```
import type { WithId, Document, ObjectId } from 'mongodb'

export default class Permissions {
    constructor(public _id: ObjectId, public collection: string, public schema: any) {}
}
```

#### Import model with:

```
import Permissions from "../../models/permissions";
```

#### Getting and typing response from mongo:

```
const permissionSchemaCollectionResponse: Permissions[] = (await permissionSchemaCollection.find(filter).toArray()) as Permissions[];

console.log('permissionSchemaCollectionResponse');
console.log(permissionSchemaCollectionResponse);

console.log(permissionSchemaCollectionResponse[0].schema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the schema type as a generic to the find method:

```
const permissions = await permissionSchemaCollection.find<PermissionSchema>(filter).toArray()
```

Comment: Do you have supporting documentation for this claim?